# Qt namespace duplicate id error

Tags: c++, qt

I hope is not a question too specific... But I will be really thankfull if you could help!

when I build my application I get this error, do you know why?:

```
ld: duplicate symbol colors::white      in mainwindow.o and main.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the definition of the main:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and here is the definition of main window:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    glwidget = new MyGLBox(ui->centralWidget);
    startTimer(11);

//test frame
    BasicShapes shapes;

    Polygon3 square = shapes.create_square(V3(0.,0.,0.),V3(1.0,1.0,1.),colors::cyan);
    Polygon3 cube = shapes.create_cube(V3(-1.,-1.,-1.),V3(1.,1.,1.),colors::purple);
    Polygon3 triangle = shapes.create_triangle(V3(0,1.,0),V3(1.,1.,1.),5.,colors::green);
    //other stuff...

    ui->vLayoutGLview->addWidget(glwidget); //add the glwidget to the ui framework 
}
```

colors is a namespace defined in the file colors.h:

```
namespace colors{
Color white(1.,1.,1.,0.);
Color black(0.,0.,0.,0.);
Color red(1.,0.,0.,0.);
Color green(0.,1.,0.,0.);
Color blue(0.,0.,1.,0.);
Color yellow(1.,1.,0.,0.);
Color purple(1.,0.,1.,0.);
Color cyan(0.,1.,1.,0.);
}
```

here is my file list:

colors.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "myglbox.h"
#include "sceneobject.h"
```

mathvector.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>    
#include "colors.h"
```

myglbox.h

```
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <vector>
#include "mathvector.h"
```

sceneobject.h

```
#include "mathvector.h"
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't included two time the same file(but maybe I missed it), and anyway the header are protected by the header guards.

do you have any idea why I get a duplicate id error? without the namespace it compiled fine, but a namespace with the standard color will be really useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects defined in a header file will be duplicated in every compilation unit that includes that header, leading to duplicate definition errors.  These should either be `extern` (and defined elsewhere), or (my preference) made into free functions:

Colors.h

```
namespace color
{
    const Color& white();
    const Color& black();
    // etc...
}
```

Colors.cpp

```
#include "colors.h"

namespace color
{
    const Color& white()
    {
       static Color w(1.,1.,1.,0.);
       return w;
    }

    const Color& black()
    {
       static Color b(0., 0., 0., 0.);
       return b;
    }
}
```

Then you can use them easily as:

```
Color white_copy = colors::white();
const Color& black = colors::black();
```

Comment: and it weeerks yeeeh! Thank you!